# WCF - Using more than one service certificate (due to certificate change)

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, x509certificate

We run a WCF service that uses (mutual) certificates for encryption and signing. So far everything is working fine.

Here's the issue: In a few weeks we need to replace the service certificate.
We'd like to implement the changes on the server and client independently from each other, so that no close coordination of the activities is needed.
Here's the steps that we'd ideally want to take:

1. Install the new service certificate in the certificate store (no problem there)
2. Configure the WCF service in a way that it can work with both the old and the new certificate.
   At this point the server should be able to accept requests that were encrypted with both the old and the new public key, depending on which key the client uses.
   The client would still be using the old certificate.
3. Configure the client to use the new certificate.
4. Delete the old certificate from the cert store.

My problem is with step 2. I can't find any reference as to how to configure the service so it is able to work with both certificates and select the correct one based on parameters in the request (e.g. the SubjectKeyIdentifier).
It seems that I specifically have to tell WCF which service certificate to use.
Below is the relevant snippet from our server config (we use a custom binding, but I guess this doesn't matter here).
In this case we identify the certificate based on the subject name.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecurityBehavior">
    ...
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
        </clientCertificate>
    <serviceCertificate  findValue="MyCertName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Question: Is it possible to get rid of the specific definition (and still have the service work), so that the service dynamically selects the correct certificate? How would that work?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you can only have one service certificate. If you cannot make the change between client and server at the same time try to set up 2 difference services, one with old cert and one with new. Then gradually migrate clients to work with the new service url/cert. If you cannot change client url but just cert you could build a server proxy that knows to route the request to the rigth server based on the certificate but try to avoid it.